# button not doing an event more than once

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am using a script which is adding a new row () after the tr in which my button (to be clicked) is.
i didnot want the SAME button to produce more than one tr . here is the script:

```
<script>

 $(function() {
        var done;
        $('table.listtable td input.selectseat').click(function() {

            if( done ) return;
            done = true;
           $(this).parent().parent().after('<tr class="seating"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>');
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

but the proiblem is that i have sequesnce of these buttons, and what this script is doing is, that its not letting me produce a row FROM ANOTHER BUTTON after i have produced a row from a button.
to clearly put it, i have a sequence of rows , each having the same button called "select seats". i wanted that EACH BUTTON  should not produce more than one button, but we can have every different button clicked and produce a row at the same time, which is not happeining.

the statement-:

```
if( done ) return;
            done = true;
```

was added to prevent the button clicked already, not to produce any more row, but its not producing a new row after one click at all for all the buttons.
please help.

Comment: use jquery .one() on the button that you want just one time click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is for.

```
$('table.listtable td input.selectseat').one('click', function() { ... } );
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, @recursive, its working now. But can you also tell me that how can i use the same .one() method for the effect that i had before, that is, only one click,, no matter how many buttons?

Comment: The code I provided should apply to all the matching elements in the entire document.